# Simple question about sequence convergence and how to formalize a proof.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If the sequence $(x_n) \rightarrow x$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and both $x_n \neq 0$ and $x \neq 0$, how do I show that the sequence $({1\over x_n}) \rightarrow \frac 1x$?

The intuition here is obvious to me. If  $x_n$ converges to $x$, then the sequence represented by the inverse of $x_n$ will converge to the inverse of $x$. And both of these expressions will be defined because neither $x_n$ nor x will be equal to $0$. You just take the inverse of every term in the first sequence, and those will be the terms in the second sequence. What I am unsure about is how exactly to formalize this idea and express it in a proof using the proper notation.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\frac{1}{x_n} - \frac{1}{x} = \frac{x-x_n}{xx_n}
$$
If $x\neq 0$ and $x_n\to x$, then there is $\delta > 0$ such that $|x_n| > \delta$ for large enough $n$, whence
$$
\left| \frac{1}{x_n} - \frac{1}{x} \right| \leq \frac{1}{|x|\delta}|x-x_n|
$$
Now can you conclude what you need?

Answer (score 1):

It is given that the sequence $(x_n)\rightarrow x$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

So, $\forall$ $\epsilon>0$, $\exists$  $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$ $\forall$ $n\ge n_0$.

Now we have, $\left| \frac{1}{x_n} - \frac{1}{x} \right| = \frac{1}{|x.x_n|}|x-x_n| < \epsilon\frac{1}{|x.x_n|}$ $...(i)$

Also, as $x_n\neq 0$ & $x \neq 0$, then we can find an $\alpha>0$ such that $|x_nx|>\alpha$.

Using this in $(i)$,

we get,

$\left| \frac{1}{x_n} - \frac{1}{x} \right| < \frac{\epsilon}{\alpha}$

We can name this $\frac{\epsilon}{\alpha}$ as $\epsilon_0$ and thus, get the required proof.

Answer (score 0):

As both $x_n \neq 0$ and $x \neq 0$, you can find $\alpha>0$ such that $\forall n, \, |x_nx|> \frac 1\alpha$ or written diffrently, $|\frac 1{x_nx}|< \alpha $

As $(x_n) \rightarrow x$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ 
one can write $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists n_o$ such that $\forall n>n_0, \, |x_n-x|<\epsilon$

for this same $n_0$ one can write,
$\forall n> n_0$
$|\frac 1{x_n }-\frac 1x|=|\frac{x_n-x}{x_nx}|< \alpha \cdot \epsilon $
Choosing $\epsilon'$ to be  equal to $\alpha \cdot \epsilon $, you can conclude